# Substring with range crashes

Tags: objective-c, substring, nsrangeexception

I am having strange problem. The following substring code crashes with

```
NSString *string4 = @"<p>some</p><img></img><p></p>end of the story":
[string4 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(7, [string4 length] - 1)];
```

I assume the range is within the boundary but it still crashes.
Any idea why this is happening ?
The following is the error it showed.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString substringWithRange:]: Range or index out of bounds'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c92012 0x10cfe7e 0x1c91deb 0x1c6aaa4 0x2bbc 0xf51c7 0xf5232 0x443d5 0x4476f 0x44905 0x4d917 0x27c5 0x11157 0x11747 0x1294b 0x23cb5 0x24beb 0x16698 0x1beddf9 0x1bedad0 0x1c07bf5 0x1c07962 0x1c38bb6 0x1c37f44 0x1c37e1b 0x1217a 0x13ffc 0x24fd 0x2425)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

Comment: at the end of first line, is it a colon (:)? It should be semicolon (;)?

Comment: Your range is bigger than your string. `substringWithRange:` will raise an exception if you try to get a substring outside the string. The arguments to `NSMakeRange` are starting point and length, not start and end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> NSMakeRange(7, [string4 length] - 1)

This range starts 7 characters from the beginning and finishes 6 characters **after** the end of the string.

A range is composed of the start location and the desired length from that location.

Comment: Arghh, my bad. I thought second parameter is the end index.  I wasted a lot of time on this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The second argument to `NSMakeRange` is the number of characters to include in the substring.  Thus it must be no more than `[string4 length] - 7`, because the starting location of the range is `7`.  Try this:

```
NSString *string4 = @"<p>some</p><img></img><p></p>end of the story":
NSUInteger start = 7;
[string4 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(start, [string4 length] - start - 1)];
```